# Проблема при конвертации типов (incompatible types)

Tags: java, java-hashmap, cast

**Дано:**

```
Map<String, Resume> storage = new HashMap<>();
```

Компаратор реализован в классе Resume

**Требуется реализовать:**

```
public final List<Resume> getAllSorted() {
        return List<Resume>;
    }
```

**Почему при такой реализации выдаёт ошибку приведения типов в строке 4?**

```
1.public final List<Resume> getAllSorted() {
2.        Object[] array = storage.values().toArray();
3.        Arrays.sort(array);
4.  return (List<Resume>) Arrays.asList(array);
    }

Ошибка выглядит так:
Error:(48, 29) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: com.urise.webapp.model.Resume
    lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

**До чего удалось докопаться:**

- в values мапы хранятся Resume
- при storage.values() мы получаем объект типа вложенного класса HashMap
- при storage.values().toArray() получаем Object[] array
- при  Arrays.asList(array) получаем ошибку приведения типов (есть Object[], а должен быть Resume[])

**Так же пробовал такой вариант во 2-ой строке:**

```
Resume[] array = (Resume[]) storage.values().toArray();
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Lcom.urise.webapp.model.Resume; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Lcom.urise.webapp.model.Resume; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

**В какой момент конвертации из Resume в Object мы потеряли возможность конвертировать обратно в Resume?**

Нашёл в интернете такое решение, всё компилится, но будто бы должно быть более правильное решение.

```
return (List<Resume>) (Object) Arrays.asList(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать без приведений типов:

```
public final List<Resume> getAllSorted() {
    
    Resume[] array = storage.values().toArray(new Resume[0]);
    Arrays.sort(array);
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

> В какой момент конвертации из Resume в Object мы потеряли возможность конвертировать обратно в Resume?

Если использовать просто `toArray()` то теряется информация о типах в массиве (все элементы приводятся к типу Object). А раз это массив с обезличенными объектами, и мы не можем дать гарантий (в общем случае), что все элементы массива могут быть приведены к заданному типу, и возникает такая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ про toArray(), буду знать теперь. За реализацию тоже спасибо. Я в итоге реализовал так: 

```public final List<Resume> getAllSorted() {    
    List<Resume> sorted = new ArrayList<>(storage.values());
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    return sorted;
}```